# How to pass class properties as parameters in class method to then console log the output in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, methods, parameter-passing

So I´m new to programming, and just a few days ago I left the structured paradigm to venture into OOP because i´m interested on making games, (I choose JS since my brother, an actual web/game dev has his engine written on it, and I want to make games with him, and also JS is awsome!) Now I started with the idea of making a small "solar system creator" to practice, and I´m already having problems from the start...

Okay, to the problem, I´m starting with the "Sun class". I would like that it´s properties such as "mass", "color", "gravity", etc to be automatically set by just putting the star type, for example:

If I create an M type star (normally a red dwarf) I would like it´s color automatically set to red (ideally to a random color in a list, but I have to start somewhere)

now, to the code:

```
class Star{
    constructor(props = {}){
        this.starType = props.starType || "M Type"
        this.starColor = props.starColor || "No color"
        this.starSize = props.starSuze || 0
        this.starHabitablePlanetChance = props.starHabitablePlanetChance + "%" || 0 + "%"
    }

    set_star_color(starType){
        starType = this.starType
        switch (starType) {
            case starType = "M Type" :
                this.starColor = "Red"        
                break;

            default:
                "No color"
                break;
        }
    }

}


let sun = new Star({
    starType : "M type"
})

console.log(sun.set_star_color())
```

my logic (a terrible one by the way) tells me that i have to ask the "sunType" as a parameter to later switch it to give it´s color (the same for the rest of the properties but in different methods, or in one big method that gives the star it´s characteristics)

Terminal output:
PS D:\VS Code\JS\Solar System> node main.js
undefined

I know what it means, but I´m strugling on how to solve it.

Thank you, and I know I´m asking too much, but if it can be an ELI5 format type of answer, it would help a ton.

Comment: "*I left the structured paradigm*" - uh, JS is still a structured programming language.

Comment: Yes sir, like many languages, JS can be treated as an OOP´language as well, exactly the thing i decided to do.  :D

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to log the return value of `sun.set_star_color()` but you're not returning anything in that function that's why you're getting `undefined`. (which is by default the return value of a function if none provided)

At the end of your program set the star color by calling `sun.set_star_color()` and then console.log your star `console.log(sun)`.

Comment: Wow, that actually clicked and made a hella lot of sense for me, thanks you, I even realized that I could do the conditional on the constructor itself.